# Facebook already authorized callback issue

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

The second time I tried to authorize an app in Facebook it gives me back a window

> You have already authorized app name. Press okay to continue.

The question is what is called back/delegate that is called after I press okay, because I somehow need a way to remove the login view controller after this

Answer (score 0):

The callback is the same as when you wasn't authorized. Same process.

Back in your application you don't even have to (and even can't) make the distinction.

Comment: and what specifically is that callback called?

Comment: Everything is in FBSessionDelegate and FBLoginDialogDelegate protocols. See FB API documentation (or UTSL)

Comment: None of the FBSessionDelegate is called back when I click okay, not sure about the FBLoginDialogDelegate

Comment: Of course you set the delegate to the right object when calling ` [_facebook authorize:FB_APP_KEY permissions:_permissions delegate:self];`?

Comment: at least I have it as facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:self];, the authorize now only takes an array of permissions

Comment: I think I figured it out. See my answer, and let me know if it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

In your `UIApplicationDelegate`, be sure that the `- (BOOL)application:handleOpenURL:` method calls `- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:` on the `Facebook` object.